# Notificaciones push en xamarin con php

Tags: php, c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Amigos estamos trabajando en una app en xamarin.forms cross platform, la cuestión es que se quiere implementar las notificaciones push tanto para el proyecto android como para el ios, la cuestión es que no se esta trabajando con el servicio de notificación de azure, ya que el app es un complemento del sistema base que se encuentra todo construido en php, la cuestión es ¿cómo puedo implementar las notificaciones push en xamarin con php sin usar azure? ¿es posible? y ¿como se haría? ya que toda la documentación que he encontrado es referente a azure y creo que es posible hacerlo con php, alguien me puede ayudar con esto.

Comment: Hola Jhonny, para implementar notificaciones push, puedes usar Firebase Notifications.

Comment: amigo @MiguelOsorio, si se utiliza FireBase pero en xamarin se utiliza un intermediario que azure, la idea es quitar azure y usar php

Answer (score 1):

> ¿es posible?

Claro que sí, no necesitas usar Azure para las notificaciones push (asumo que hablas del servicio de Azure Notification Hub).

> ¿cómo puedo implementar las notificaciones push en xamarin con php sin usar azure?

Puedes revisar este enlace donde ya se ha respondido esta pregunta para que veas cómo funciona la integración: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase

Desde tu servidor debes conectarte al servicio de notificaciones de Firebase siguiendo la documentación oficial:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol

Y para recibir notificaciones, puedes usar este plugin para Xamarin.Forms https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin y seguir su documentación.

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible.

Debes configurar tu aplicación en Google Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419

Para enviar la notificación desde PHP debes usar CURL, algo parecido al siguiente código:

```
public function SendGlobalNotification($Message)
{
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

                                $headers = array(
                                    'Authorization: key=' . 'AAAAZjH-iIw:APA91bGc1NPUOJfHlsgu_f8SxTvisH86-4QEZxun5l6Mn6vbv9XwTjesELMAXR2vlGnCuX6znafH8SsX5bagh9-Rf4SUgmTpNPZZ73meSfFfG5zTzqZuy9GSS2t1zCREUKtv0HX-gEEp',
                                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                                );

        $msg = array('body' => $Message);

        $fields = array
                    (
                        'to'        => '/topics/user',
                        'notification'  => $msg
                    );

        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarily
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
}
```

Y para recibir la notificación en las Aplicaciones Móviles debes usar la librería de Google Firebase: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows